# Convert c++ opencv IplImage imageData and widthStep to android opencv Mat

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I'm developing an android app using opencv.
I have an algorithm written in C++ which uses opencv and I am porting it to java.
The original code uses 'IplImage' but now I'm forced to use 'Mat'. I managed to convert most of the code but I'm facing a problem with the following instructions:

```
IplImage *src;
src->imageData;
src->widthStep;
```

Can I use

```
[JAVA - Mat]src.dataAddr()  as an equivalent for [C++ - IplImage]src ->imageData
```

**and**

```
[JAVA - Mat]src.step1(0) as an equivalent for [C++ - IplImage]src->widthStep ?
```

The only link I found inherent to this topic is [this one](http://answers.opencv.org/question/8893/imagedata-and-depth-from-a-mat-object/) which explains how to convert 'IplImage' to 'Mat' but still in C++. I can't use javacv.

Thanks

Comment: For depth, Mat class has a method `depth()` - http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#depth()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For depth, [Mat class has a method `depth()`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#depth()).

The `widthStep` is a little tricky, because the `step` of Mat is not exactly the same as the `widthStep` in IplImage, but the multiple-of-four widthStep does not seem to be needed anymore. [**Here**](http://answers.opencv.org/question/20407/matstep-iplimagewidthstep/) is an interesting answer to read. That said, [Mat class also has a method for getting the `step`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#step1()).

About `imageData`, I am not sure what exactly the imageData of IplImage contained, but with Mat, you can get data from of individual pixels by looping through the matrix and using methods like `get(int row, int col)`. Go through the [documentation of Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Mat.html). I am sure you will get many options.

In the start of the doc, there is a discussion about IplImage and Mat and how the data is saved in Mat vs that in IplImage. Search for

> So, the data layout in Mat is fully compatible with CvMat, IplImage,
>   and CvMatND types from OpenCV 1.x.

and read around it.

Also read around

> Partial yet very common cases of this *user-allocated data* case are
>   conversions from CvMat and IplImage to Mat. For this purpose, there
>   are special constructors taking pointers to CvMat or IplImage and the
>   optional flag indicating whether to copy the data or not.